# "Бескомпромиссный" пишется с двумя буквами с?

Tags: орфография

Почему слово "бескомпромиссный" пишется с двумя буквами с?

Answer (score 2):

Потому что слово "компромисс" тоже пишется с этой удвоенной согласной. Словарное слово.

Comment: спасибо)))